# simpler way of checking multiple conditions in if statements python

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

`if char != ' ' and char != '\n'`

is there a simpler / shorter way of doing this, like something like this:

`if char != (' ' and '\n')`
but this doesn't work apparently

Comment: `if char not in (' ', '\n')`

Answer (score 1):

You can build a list(for higher speed, use set instead) of strings to check, something like

```
if char not in [' ', '\n']:
```

Since the example you gave are all 1 in length, you can replace the list with a longer string of those minor strings

```
" \n"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is briefer

```
if not char in ' \n':
```

```
if not char in 'abcd':
```